# Find all functions : $f(x)+f(\frac{x}{2})= \frac{x}{2}$

Tags: functional-equations

Find all functions $f : \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$  satisfying
$$f(x)+f(\frac{x}{2})= \frac{x}{2}$$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

---

My Attempt :

$-\frac{x}{3} + f(x) = \frac{x}{6} - f(\frac{x}{2})$

Let $g(x) = f(x) - \frac{x}{3}$

so $g(x)=-g(\frac{x}{2})\;$  $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+$

then $g(x)=g(\frac{x}{4})$

Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: If we assume that $f$ is continuous at $0$, by plugging in $x = 0$ we obtain $f(0) = 0$. Then also $g(0) = 0$. For any $x > 0$ we have:

$$g(x) = g\left(\frac{x}{4}\right) = g\left(\frac{x}{16}\right) =  \ldots = g\left(\frac{x}{4^n}\right) \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} g(0) = 0$$

So, $g \equiv 0$, meaning $f(x) = \frac{x}3, \forall x > 0$. But, $f$ is not even defined at $0$, let alone continuous.

Comment: Why $f$ is not defined at $0$ ?

Comment: Well usually $R^+$ means positive numbers, thus 0 is excluded.

Comment: @mechanodroid, "If we assume that $f$ is continuous at $0$, by plugging in $x=0$ we obtain $f(0)=0$. Then also $g(0)=0$." Since $0$ is not in the domain, why can we get $f(0)=0$ and $g(0)=0$ ?

Comment: We can't, not in this case. I was just pointing out the solution of the same functional equation where $f : [0, +\infty\rangle \to [0, +\infty\rangle$ and $f$ is assumed to be continuous at $0$.

Comment: @mechanodroid, So we can't conclude that $g(0)=0$ and $f(x) = \frac{x}3, \forall x > 0$, right ?

Comment: @carat No. I was talking about a different problem, basically.

Comment: @mechanodroid, could you please solve my problem using knowledge at high school level ?

Comment: You have a solution already. It's not a unique function. I have no idea how to solve it more elementary.

Comment: @mechanodroid. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x=2^z$. The equation is

$$f(2^z)+f(2^{z-1})=2^{z-1},$$ or

$$g(z)+g(z-1)=2^{z-1},$$ which is an ordinary linear recurrence.

The solution of the homogeneous equation $g(z)+g(z-1)=0$ is, by induction,

$$g(z)=(-1)^{\lfloor z\rfloor} g(\{z\})$$ where $\{z\}$ denotes the fractional part.

A particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation is

$$\frac23 e^{z-1}$$ (by undeterminate coefficients on $g(z)=ce^{z-1}$).

Finally,

$$f(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor\log_2x\rfloor}g(\{\log_2x\})+\frac x3$$ for some function $g$ defined on $[0,1)$.

If you want $f$ continuous, then $g$ must be continuous and $f(1^-)=f(1^+)$, or

$$(-1)^{-1}g(1^-)=(-1)^0g(0^+).$$

Comment: Why $g(z)+g(z-1)=0$ is homogeneous ?

Comment: @carat: review the theory of linear ODE or finite-difference equations and the decomposition as homogeneous/non-homogeneous.